# Bootstrap `list-group` inherit size of `panel`

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="list-group">
        <ul class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Item one</a></ul>
        <ul class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Item two</a></ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1e3erxt/

It's a clickable list-group within a regular panel. On high enough resolutions, there is no problem. However, when resolution drops below say 720p, the list-group starts taking less than the whole panel body: it's height remains the same, but the width starts taking 2/3 of the panel-body, and it shrinks as the resolution gets smaller.

How can I make it take the full size of the panel-body at all times?

Comment: Not in Chrome or FireFox, it's not changing width on smaller viewport widths.

Comment: I'm not seeing it in firefox either

Comment: It's inside a <div class="col-md-3">, does that affect it?

Comment: It doesn't act as described for me. However, I have noticed you're using a wrong markup, you NEED to use `<li>` inside `<ul>`, so maybe that's where your issue is

Comment: Its working fine http://www.bootply.com/9KPCLzxIBr

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use minimum-width:

```
.list-group { 
    margin: 0; 
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Now, even browser screen is lower then the list-group wouldn't be decreased from 400 pixels but in higher res screen it would be 100% width.